# If the prayer leader does not distinguish between Gimmel and Ghimmel for Amida he can't be yotzi for others

Tags: halacha, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, chazzan-prayer-leader, pronunciation

I was at a Shabbat table and someone told me that, according to Hacham Ovadia Yosef, the one leading the prayers cannot *motzi* others (i.e. cannot relieve others' prayer obligations) if he does not distinguish between Gimmel and Ghimmel.

I had never heard of this before, and he didn't have a source to provide. He said he had read it or heard it, but couldn't remember where. Does anyone have a source for this?

Comment: For those wondering what a Ghimmel (refuyah) sounds like, here is an enjoyable example: [Naghillah Halleluyah Naghillah](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqGQjRPC3Co). A classic at Sepharadi Shabbat tables.

Comment: I can guess what it sounds like. Like chaf but vocal. What does the Maghen Avraham rule on this?

Answer (score 2):

While not the pesaq (Halakhic ruling) of Hakham 'Ovadiah A"H himself, his son Hakham Yitzhaq Yosef SheLIT"A, who more frequently than not rules like his father, [states](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_4.html#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%A0%D7%92B-B%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AAB%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%97B%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8B%D7%90%D7%AAB%D7%9E%D7%99B%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9DB%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%97B%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%99) (my translation and emphasis) in Qitzur Shulhhan Arukh, Yalqut Yosef (Orahh Hayim 53:10):

> אין ממנים שליח צבור למי שאינו מבטא את האותיות כתקנן, כגון שקורא לאות חי''ת כמו כ''ף רפויה, או כמו ה''א. וכן אם קורא לאות עי''ן כמו אל''ף. ואף על פי שקולו ערב והעם מרוצים ממנו וחפצים בו, אין ראוי למנותו לשליח צבור. ואפילו אם על-ידי טורח יכול לבטא האותיות כהוגן, יש לחוש שמא לא יתן לבו כראוי ויקרא האותיות בשיבוש. ורק אם אין שליח צבור הגון כמותו, מותר למנותו לשליח צבור
>
> **One must not designate the role of Sheliahh Tzibbur to one who is unable to pronounce the letters properly**. For example, if he reads the letter Het like a Kaf refuyah or like a Heh. So, too, if he reads the letter 'Ayin like an Alef. And even if his voice is beautiful and the congregation is pleased with him and desire his talent (lit. him), it is not proper to designate him as Sheliahh Tzibbur. And even if, with great effort, he is able to pronounce the letters properly, one must be concerned that he will not exert enough effort and will read the letters improperly. **And only if there is no other Sheliahh Tzibbur as fitting as he is it permissible to designate him as Sheliahh Tzibbur.**

Comment: i've heard that before, but to distinguish between Gimmel and Ghimmel is a lot more rare, and i've run across very few Jews who do it. So it seems a bit beyond belief to me that Ovadia Yosef would make such a comment

Comment: Unless we find the an exact match from Hakham 'Ovadiah's rulings, it may be safe to assume that someone heard or read this pesaq and extrapolated thereof. Are you sure your friend was specifically referring to the Gimmel?

Comment: Yep, he was specifically referring to Gimmel, and he said that the ruling was specific to the Gimmel for the Amidah

Comment: Very well. If you think this answer is irrelevant, I am happy to remove it. If you think it adds value and/or may be the pesaq your friend meant, I will leave it up.

Comment: @Lee Regardless of whether this answer is the one the OP's friend was referring to, it _is_ relevant and you _should_ leave it up.

Comment: IMHO, this source doesn't answer the problem specific to the letter Gimel, which is what the O.P. asked.

Comment: There is a big difference between the cases he mentions and the OP. The cases he mentions sound like other letters, thus meaning the person is pronouncing the wrong word. There are no two competing letters here, just two ways to pronounce the same letter, so the "pgam" would be less.

Comment: @Yishai Indeed AFAIK, BGDKPT changes never alter the meaning.

Comment: This is not his chidush. It's a gemara in Megila 24b brought in Shulchan Aruch 53 12. Applying this to gimmel/jimmel would be a chidush. (Especially considering that the achronim said if everyone in that community pronounces it wrong, there is no issue)

Comment: @user6591 Why would applying to ghimmel/gimmel be a chiddush?

Comment: 1st of all your comment to yishai. Second of all the fact that the vast majority of people, even sfardim, do not differentiate. Third of all, even if they did and we all did and it is wrong and it means something else, if in context It could only mean what he meant it to mean, that would also be fine. Its no worse than calling Aharon Haron.

Comment: @DoubleAA "BGDKPT changes never alter the meaning" - I don't know if that's universally true. IIRC, in the beginning of Megilat Esther, it must be pronounced "ritzfat" (soft feh) meaning "floor" as pronouncing it as "ritzpat" (hard peh) is a different shoresh and changes the meaning to "glowing coal".

Comment: @DanF The correct word there is 'ritzefat' with a shva na'. Ritzpat with a shva nach derives from Ritzpa as in the Haftara for Yitro. The dagesh kal is a side-effect in a sense. Had the letter under consideration been anything else, it is the shva alone that would have demarcated the difference. I would not correct for 'ritzepat' even if that is technically a mistake.

Comment: @Everyone i remember more specifically what the person said, it was linked with the first blessing of the Amidah, someone who does not distinguish between Megen Avraham, and Maghen Avraham